# How to disable click in angular high-chart data points?

Tags: angular, highcharts

[image: I need to disable click in marked area, do you know any option to do that?]

I have tried to disable detailed click view from the high chart. I have marked yellow in image, Can anyone share option to disable click events.

Answer (score 2):

Just to add to Nirmalya's earlier comment, as he correctly pointed out on how to handle a click event. If you want to disable the interactive tooltip and on hover animation, you could alter the above example to include the following option:

```
plotOptions:{
  series:{
    enableMouseTracking: false
  }
}
```

Have a look at http://jsfiddle.net/nf94sv0u/

Having said that, I am not aware of any click events enabled by default in your chart type, other than the tooltip and hover over animation so please elaborate more on it or provide a code snippet for better understanding.

Comment: It disabled hover too.

Answer (score 1):

Not very clear which click you want to disable.
Inside plot option you can manipulate the click behavior for a series.

```
plotOptions:{
        series:{
            events:{
                click: function(e){
                     //do something
                }
            }
        }
    },
```

see this example.
http://jsfiddle.net/0tLh4ykg/1/

Comment: I have tried this, and added  
{                     e.preventDefault();
                      e.stopPropagation();
                      e.stopImmediatePropagation();
                      return false;
}
But it is going to detailed view

Answer (score 1):

It is enough if you don't define `drilldown` property for a particular data point:

```
    series: [{
        ...,
        data: [{
                ...,
                y: 62.74,
                drilldown: "Chrome"
            },
            ...,
            {
                ...,
                y: 7.62
            }
        ]
    }]
```

---

**Live example:** https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/fdxb1cj7/

**API Reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.timeline.data.drilldown

---

But if you want to disable drilldown behavior for a point with assigned drilldown just return `false` from `drilldown` event callback function. Example below with disabled click for the first point.

```
events: {
  drilldown: function(e) {
    if (e.category === 0 || e.point.index === 0) {
      return false;
    }
  }
}
```

---

**Live demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/bvxjafm9/

**API Reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/chart.events.drilldown

Comment: Actually it is dynamic data for year, and i dont want any click inside graph at any point not for a single point, But hover need to work

Comment: Hi @Justin J, So returning `false` from the `drilldown` function should be enough, example: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/70864hnf/